# Trying to get Teradata Covalent working with Meteor / Angular2

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-meteor

Im trying to get (Teradata)Covalent working with Meteor / Angular2. I've cloned `github.com/bsliran/angular2-meteor-base`, followed the Getting started instructions from the Covalent site:

```
Meteor npm install --save @covalent/core
```

> npm complains that `@angular/platform-server@2.4.5` requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@2.4.5 but none was installed.

App.Module.ts:

```
import { CovalentCoreModule } from '@covalent/core';
```

and add the following to @NgModule imports section:

```
  // Modules
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CovalentCoreModule.forRoot()
```

Test app throws exceptions -

Comment: All is woking now. I tried again using latest version and all is good. Seems that before was possibly a clash of versions